# NSMutableDictionary issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to insert an object in my dictionary, but first, I want to test if it's a NSMutableDictionary :

```
if ([[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
        [[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0]setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Y"];
    }
```

I get this issue :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Comment: Look at the doc of `isKindOfClass`, there is a beautiful example with the "NOT TO DO THIS" which matches your issue.

Comment: Try this: `id dictionary = [[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
    [dictionary setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Y"];`. This more readable.
}

Comment: @Nabil El Is `self.response` mutable?

Comment: @bsarr007 readability is not his issue.

Comment: @whitewolf09 sure, but this would help readers! And improve his question.

Comment: @bsarr007 that's why there's an EDIT button in the question section  itself. :)

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Yes it's mutable

Comment: @whitewolf09 I agree with you but i can't really change his code before he test it programmatically inside his program, this is not typo!

Comment: check `NSLog(@"%@",[[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0] class]);` what it prints.

Comment: Well this is wrong to do so.... You should make a `mutableCopy` of this then you can update it. It is getting crash because of immutable object. `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy]; [dict setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Y"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isMemberOfClass` instead of `isKindOfClass`

Comment: Why this should work and no the isKindOfClass, can you be more explicit?

Comment: Because NSDictionary is a cluster class. ie Although you call it an NSDictionary / NSMutableDictionary, what you are actually given by the initializer (or instance type) is an undocumented subclass..  do some reading on class clusters. NSArray is another

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the same selector which is crashing,

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(setObject:forKey:)]) {
    //If YES, it is NSMutableDictionary
}
else { 
    //Not mutable
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if ([[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[self.response objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex:0]];
    [dict setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Y"];
    NSMutableArray *xArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.response objectForKey:@"X"]];
    [xArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dict];
    [self.response setObject:xArray forKey:@"X"];
}
```

Comment: Yes, This is correct answer. I don't think that `isKindOfClass:` is needed here.